# navigation class PHP

Tags: php

Hello I am learning OOP programming in PHP and I was trying to create a Navigation class ( with correct OOP structure ) but somehow I can't make it work. i'm not sure if the classes are wrong or that I call them in a wrong way.. can somebody take a look and help me with this please :) see my code below

Navigation class:

```
<?php
class Navigation implements navigationInterface{

    public $menu = null;
    public $name = null;
    public $klasse = null;
    public $items = null;

    public function __construct($name, $klasse) {

        $this->name = $name;
        $this->klasse = $klasse;

    }

    public function addChild(NavigationItem $item)
    {
        $this->items[] = $item;
    }

    public function getName() {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function getClass() {
        return $this->klasse;
    }


    public function display() {

        $menu = '<nav class="' . $this->getName() . '"><ul>';

        foreach ($this->items as $item) {

           $menu.= $item->display();

        }

        $menu .= '</ul></nav>';

        return $menu;

    }
}
?>
```

and my Navigation Item class ( to add items )

```
<?php
class NavigationItem implements NavigationItemInterface {

    public $menu = null;

    public function setMenuItem($items) {

        $this->menuItem = $items;
    }

    public function getMenuItem() {
        return $items;
    }

    public function display() {


        return '<li><a class="' . $this->getClass() . '" href="index.php?page=' . $this->getMenuItem() . '.php">' . $this->getMenuItem() . '</a></li>';

    }

}
?>
```

and here is how I tought I should call the class

```
<?php
$menu = new Navigation("navigation", "mainmenu");
$items = new NavigationItem();
$menu_items = array("home", "about", "playground");
$items->setMenuItem($menu_items);
$menu->addChild($items);
echo $menu->display();

?>
```

Comment: The logic in it.. it doesn;t make sense actually because my code uses methods from both classes is this correct and how do I use this if so..

Comment: Well what HTML does it spit out? We can't help if we don't know what's wrong!

Comment: Common people, he assigns an array to NavigationItem where it should be a string. Strong typing FTW

Answer (score 0):

The problem is 'it doesn't work'. Try this. Btw  in Navigation class those public fields should be private.

```
<?php
   $menu = new Navigation("navigation", "mainmenu");
   $menu_items = array("home", "about", "playground");
   foreach($menu_items as $item) 
   { 
   $items = new NavigationItem();
   $items->setMenuItem($item);
   $menu->addChild($items);
    }
  echo $menu->display();
```

?>

Comment: thanks for your answer. but I get the error: 
Fatal error: Call to undefined method NavigationItem::getClass() in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/projectx/lib/NavigationItem.php on line 18 because I use a method of Navigation in the NavigationItem class

Comment: right. So pass the Navigation as as dependency of NavigationItem

Comment: that's for you to find out. hint: it goes into the constructor

Comment: ah sorry I read your sentence wrong :p i've passed it but now I get another error..Notice: Undefined variable: items in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/projectx/lib/NavigationItem.php on line 20

Comment: You know it is very simple if you actually read your own code and try to understand what it tries to do. You are returning $items when THERE IS NO field defined with that name. And the message error is a big hint. In fact i wonder how I missed so many obvious errors. You declare fields you don't use, you use fields that are not declared etc. It's like you're trolling or something. I can write the correct code for you, but what good would be that for you? You need to understand things not just copy/paste them